# SQL update function, know which cell I want, how to find row

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

I want to update a row like this:

```
_id, AttributeA, AttributeB, AttributeC
```

I need to find a row based on `AttributeC` so that I can update it, lets say the desired `AttributeC` contains value `"X"`

How would this be done?
I believe this would be done with a WHERE argument but can I get this whole statement spelled out?

Comment: by contains do you mean equal or actually contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE table
SET AttributeB='value'
WHERE AttributeA = 'X'
```

This will update all rows where AttributeA = 'X' and set AttributeB to 'value', if there are more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at the [UPDATE syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).  If you get stuck, show us what you've tried and we can help further

Comment: hey, thanks for the references. I am actually using a wrapper sdk in Java and I got to a place where one function needed actual SQL statement in this one case, I'll bookmark that

Answer (score 1):

```
update TableA 
set AttributeC = 'XXX' 
where AttributeC like "%X%"
```